# DialogFragment with Navigation Component (Orientation Issue)

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

> Navigation Component 2.3.0-aplha06

I am having a dialog fragment in the navigation graph along with few fragment.

> Scenario - Happy

Fragment A opens and on click of button navigate to DialogFragment
Dialog Fragment simulates some progress and after it completes it performs

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

Then Fragment A perform some action and navigate to Fragment B.

> Scenario - Sad

Fragment A opens and on click of button navigate to DialogFragment
Dialog Fragment simulates some progress
User change orientation of the device from portrait to landscape

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

Then Fragment A perform some action and navigate to Fragment B.

```
2020-05-13 10:53:32.436 15140-15140/com.demo.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.demo.example, PID: 15140
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ProgressDialogFragment{1765f4f} (7df114f6-88cf-4d24-9b07-54c0ff9edcb0)} not associated with a fragment manager.
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getParentFragmentManager(Fragment.java:945)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.findNavController(NavHostFragment.java:107)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentKt.findNavController(Fragment.kt:29)
        at com.demo.example.ProgressDialogFragment$PaymentTimer.onFinish(ProgressDialogFragment.kt:61)
        at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Code of ProgressDialogFragment

```
class ProgressDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

private lateinit var txtProgressBar: DxpTextView

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).apply {
        window?.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        window?.setLayout(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
        window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        isCancelable = false
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_progress_dialog, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    txtProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_progress_text)

    val timer = PaymentTimer(5000, 2500)
    timer.start()
}

inner class PaymentTimer(
    millisInFuture: Long,
    countDownInterval: Long
) : CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {

    override fun onFinish() {
        findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("progress", true)
        findNavController().popBackStack()
    }

    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        if (millisUntilFinished < 2500 && isAdded) {
            txtProgressBar.text = getString(R.string.progress_msg_2)
        }

    }
}}
```

Comment: Your `onFinish()` is not running after your `ProgressDialogFragment` is destroyed, that is a memory leak. Can you include your `ProgressDialogFragment`'s code?

Comment: @ianhanniballake updated with ProgressDialogFragment Code